# C# Immutable counter for multiple fields

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, immutable-collections

I have a fairly high throughput on a message counter (tens of thousands per second), and looking for an efficient way of getting the count without putting locks everywhere or ideally not locking on each message count when i am giving an update every 10 seconds.

**Use of immutable counter object**

I am using an immutable counter class:

```
public class Counter
{
    public Counter(int quotes, int trades)
    {
        Quotes = quotes;
        Trades = trades;
    }

    readonly public int Quotes;
    readonly public int Trades;
    // and some other counter fields snipped
}
```

And would update this on each message process loop:

```
class MyProcessor
{
    System.Timers.Timer timer;
    Counter counter = new Counter(0,0);

    public MyProcessor()
    {
       // update ever 10 seconds
       this.timer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);

       timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => {
          var quotesPerSecond = this.counter.Quotes / 10.0;
          var tradesPerSecond = this.counter.Trades / 10.0;
          this.Counter = new Counter(0,0);
       });
    }

    public void ProcessMessages(Messages messages)
    {
       foreach(var message in messages) { /* */ }

       var oldCounter = counter;
       this.counter = new Counter(oldCounter.Quotes, oldCounter.Trades);   
    }
}
```

I have lots of counters (not all shown), so would mean a lot of individual `Interlocked.Increment` calls on individual counter fields.

The only other way I can think of is lock every single run of `ProcessMessages` (which will be extensive) and heavy for something which is a utility as opposed to critical where the program would crash.

Is it possible to use an immutable counter object in this fashion without hard interlocking/thread mechanisms when we only need to update once every 10 seconds?

**Flag check idea to avoid locks**

Could the timer thread set a flag for the `ProcessMessages` to check and if it sees it set, start the count from zero again, i.e.

```
/* snipped the MyProcessor class, same as before */

System.Timers.Timer timer;
Counter counter = new Counter(0,0);
ManualResetEvent reset = new ManualResetEvent(false);

public MyProcessor()
{
   // update ever 10 seconds
   this.timer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);

   timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => {
      var quotesPerSecond = this.counter.Quotes / 10.0;
      var tradesPerSecond = this.counter.Trades / 10.0;
      // log
      this.reset.Set();
   });
}

// this should be called every second with a heartbeat message posted to queue
public void ProcessMessages(Messages messages)
{
   if (reset.WaitOne(0) == true)
   {
      this.counter = new Counter(this.counter.Quotes, this.counter.Trades, this.counter.Aggregates);
      reset.Reset();
   }
   else
   {
      this.counter = new Counter(
                        this.counter.Quotes + message.Quotes.Count,
                        this.counter.Trades + message.Trades.Count);
   }
}

/* end of MyProcessor class */
```

This would work, however the update "stalls" when the process messages comes to a halt (although the throughput is very high, it does pause for a number of hours at night ideally should show the actual rather than last value).

One way around this would be to post a heartbeat message to the `MyProcessor.ProcessMessages()` every second to force an internal update of the message counters and subsequent reset when the `reset` ManualResetEvent is set.

Comment: Your counter is far from immutable. You're exposing the public fields directly, and they're not read-only. How is that immutable? (If this is high throughput, you might want to reconsider a design that requires a new object to be created very frequently, too.)

Comment: apologies, late night, added the readonly missed accidently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to update everyone with what I had come up with, the counter updates were pushed within the thread itself.

Everything is driven by the `DequeueThread` loop, and specifically `this.queue.ReceiveAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(UpdateFrequencySeconds))` function.

This will either return an item from the queue, process it and update the counters, or timeout and then update the counters - there are no other threads involved everything, including updating message rate, is done within the thread.

In summary, nothing runs in parallel (in terms of dequing the packet), it is fetching the items one at a time and processing it and the counters thereafter. Then finally looping back to process the next item in the queue.

This removes the need for synchronisation:

```
internal class Counter
{
    public Counter(Action<int,int,int,int> updateCallback, double updateEvery)
    {
        this.updateCallback = updateCallback;
        this.UpdateEvery = updateEvery;
    }

    public void Poll()
    {
        if (nextUpdate < DateTimeOffset.UtcNow)
        {
            // post the stats, and reset
            this.updateCallback(this.quotes, this.trades, this.aggregates, this.statuses);
            this.quotes = 0;
            this.trades = 0;
            this.aggregates = 0;
            this.statuses = 0;
            nextUpdate = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddSeconds(this.UpdateEvery);
        }
    }

    public void AddQuotes(int count) => this.quotes += count;
    public void AddTrades(int count) => this.trades += count;
    public void AddAggregates(int count) => this.aggregates += count;
    public void AddStatuses(int count) => this.statuses += count;

    private int quotes;
    private int trades;
    private int aggregates;
    private int statuses;

    private readonly Action<int,int,int,int> updateCallback;
    public double UpdateEvery { get; private set; }
    private DateTimeOffset nextUpdate;
}

public class DeserializeWorker
{
    private readonly BufferBlock<byte[]> queue = new BufferBlock<byte[]>();
    private readonly IPolygonDeserializer polygonDeserializer;
    private readonly ILogger<DeserializeWorker> logger;

    private readonly Counter counter; 
    const double UpdateFrequencySeconds = 5.0;        
    long maxBacklog = 0;

    public DeserializeWorker(IPolygonDeserializer polygonDeserializer, ILogger<DeserializeWorker> logger)
    {
        this.polygonDeserializer = polygonDeserializer ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(polygonDeserializer));
        this.logger = logger;
        this.counter = new Counter(ProcesCounterUpdateCallback, UpdateFrequencySeconds);
    }

    public void Add(byte[] data)
    {
        this.queue.Post(data);
    }

    public Task Run(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        return Task
                .Factory
                .StartNew(
                    async () => await DequeueThread(stoppingToken),
                    stoppingToken,
                    TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning,
                    TaskScheduler.Default)
                .Unwrap();
    }

    private async Task DequeueThread(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested == false)
        {
            try
            {
                var item = await this.queue.ReceiveAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(UpdateFrequencySeconds), stoppingToken);
                await ProcessAsync(item);
            }
            catch (TimeoutException)
            {
                // this is ok, timeout expired 
            }
            catch(TaskCanceledException)
            {
                break; // task cancelled, break from loop
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                this.logger.LogError(e.ToString());
            }

            UpdateCounters();
        }

        await StopAsync();
    }


    protected async Task StopAsync()
    {
        this.queue.Complete();
        await this.queue.Completion;
    }

    protected void ProcessStatuses(IEnumerable<Status> statuses)
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(statuses, (current) =>
        {
            if (current.Result != "success")
                this.logger.LogInformation($"{current.Result}: {current.Message}");
        });
    }

    protected void ProcessMessages<T>(IEnumerable<T> messages)
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(messages, (current) =>
        {
            // serialize by type T
            // dispatch
        });
    }

    async Task ProcessAsync(byte[] item)
    {
        try
        {
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(item);
            var message = await this.polygonDeserializer.DeserializeAsync(memoryStream);

            var messagesTask = Task.Run(() => ProcessStatuses(message.Statuses));
            var quotesTask = Task.Run(() => ProcessMessages(message.Quotes));
            var tradesTask = Task.Run(() => ProcessMessages(message.Trades));
            var aggregatesTask = Task.Run(() => ProcessMessages(message.Aggregates));

            this.counter.AddStatuses(message.Statuses.Count);
            this.counter.AddQuotes(message.Quotes.Count);
            this.counter.AddTrades(message.Trades.Count);
            this.counter.AddAggregates(message.Aggregates.Count);

            Task.WaitAll(messagesTask, quotesTask, aggregatesTask, tradesTask);                                
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            this.logger.LogError(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    void UpdateCounters()
    {
        var currentCount = this.queue.Count;
        if (currentCount > this.maxBacklog)
            this.maxBacklog = currentCount;

        this.counter.Poll();
    }

    void ProcesCounterUpdateCallback(int quotes, int trades, int aggregates, int statuses)
    {
        var updateFrequency = this.counter.UpdateEvery;
        logger.LogInformation(
            $"Queue current {this.queue.Count} (max {this.maxBacklog }), {quotes / updateFrequency} quotes/sec, {trades / updateFrequency} trades/sec, {aggregates / updateFrequency} aggregates/sec, {statuses / updateFrequency} status/sec");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that this lock-free solution produces correct results? I would be very concerned if I was in your place!

Comment: Thanks @TheodorZoulias for the message :) Yes it is running OK and seems to produce the right results, have updated my answer to include rationale of the "one item dequeued at a time". I have also included an update to your response to a different (but related question) with regards to task creation, that makes perfect sense thank you.

Comment: TBH there is a lot of code in your answer, and I can't reason if it's thread-safe or not by just looking at it (considering that there is too much horizontal scrolling needed in order to read it). So if you say that it produces correct results, I'm not going to dispute it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here are three new methods for your `Counter` class. One for reading the latest value from a specific location, one for updating safely a specific location, and one for creating easily a new `Counter` based on an existing one:

```
public static Counter Read(ref Counter counter)
{
    return Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref counter, null, null);
}

public static void Update(ref Counter counter, Func<Counter, Counter> updateFactory)
{
    var counter1 = counter;
    while (true)
    {
        var newCounter = updateFactory(counter1);
        var counter2 = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref counter, newCounter, counter1);
        if (counter2 == counter1) break;
        counter1 = counter2;
    }
}

public Counter Add(int quotesDelta, int tradesDelta)
{
    return new Counter(Quotes + quotesDelta, Trades + tradesDelta);
}
```

Usage example:

```
Counter latest = Counter.Read(ref this.counter);

Counter.Update(ref this.counter, existing => existing.Add(1, 1));
```

Accessing the `MyProcessor.counter` field directly by multiple threads concurrently is not thread-safe, because it's neither [`volatile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/volatile) nor protected by a `lock`. The above methods are safe to use because they are accessing the field through [interlocked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked) operations.

Comment: Thanks Theodor for taking the time to reply and the insight, I was able to resolve this without any locks by updating the counter inline within the thread itself, I have posted a answer for this. Again thanks for the response.